# How to use push() in array inside mapping?

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

i want to use push function in array inside mapping

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
contract mappingStruct {

mapping (uint=>string[]) mappingAndArray;
function addToMapping(uint myKey,string[] memory name)public{
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems straightforward enough. Is this what you had in mind?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract MappingPush {

    mapping (uint256 => string[]) public myArrays;

    function pushTo(uint256 key, string calldata toAdd) public {
        myArrays[key].push(toAdd);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (tested in Remix). This will assign a string array to each `myKey`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
   contract mappingStruct {

   mapping (uint=>string[]) mappingAndArray;

   function addToMapping(uint myKey,string[] memory name)public{
       mappingAndArray[myKey] = name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Not work i want to use push function